# Changing the value of a dependency property doesn't fire a property value changed event in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I built a `UserControl` with a dependency property like this:

```
public MyUserContol()
{                
    InitializeComponent();
    SelectedString = "Defalut";
}

public string SelectedString
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedStringProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedStringProperty, value); }
} 

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedString.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedStringProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedString", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserContol),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnSelectedStringPropertyChanged));

private static void OnSelectedStringPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source,
                                                    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (source as MyUserContol).SelectedSatringChanged();
}
```

When I use it, it's working fine

```
<UserContol:MyUserControl SelectedClient="blabla" />
```

but in a `DataTemplate` it dosn't work!

```
<DataGrid1:DataGrid x:Name="dg"   ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}">
    <DataGrid1:DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="[Client]" Header="Date" >
            <DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserContol:MyUserControl SelectedClient="blabla" >
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGrid1:DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid1:DataGrid>
```

Its not changing the value to "blabla".  I know it's not working because the `OnSelectedStringPropertyChanged` isn't being invoked!  The property stays the default value given from the constructor.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Another possibility is that you're calling the wrong method in your property changed event.  You're calling `SelectedSatringChanged()` and not `SelectedStringChanged()`.  There's a lot of spelling inconsistencies in that code snippet so I can't tell if it's just another typo or an actual mistake in your code.

Comment: The tag `<UserContol:MyUserControl>` is not closed. Is that a typo? Maybe the xaml is not valid

Comment: this code written good with the correct methos and propties names, all this mistakes are because i change the method and proprties names when i moved the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !!!

i needed to remove from the Ctor this code:

```
  SelectedString = "Defalut";
```